# Do Facebook Graph API calls using field expansion count differently against the rate limits than batch calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, limit, facebook-field-expansion

I am looking to optimize my Facebook app.

Today I make a batch call with four graph API calls:

```
/me
/me/friends
/me/likes
/me/feed
```

If I change this to a single graph API call using field expansion like this:

```
/me?fields=id,name,username,friends,likes,feed
```

Will that now count as one hit against the API instead of four for rate limiting purposes?

Comment: Yes, it should, everything else would make little sense.

Comment: I agree that this seems obvious, but the FB rate limiting is pretty opaque, so I'd just like to hear the FB folks validate the assumption.

Comment: Your second call *is* a single API call. You aren't using field expansion in it.

Comment: Ah thx cpilko ... that's true even when the "fields" are connections (friends, likes, feed)?

Comment: @CBroe I do understand your answer, i thought exactly the same! However after some digging on the Facebook developers website I found out that each api call in the batch is counted, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, each call in the batch is counted as an api call, it's just faster to call them within a batch since it will be 1 request. See here documentation on Facebook API:

**Limits** 
We currently limit the number of requests which can be in a batch to 50, but each call within the batch is counted separately for the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits. For example, a batch of 10 API calls will count as 10 calls and each call within the batch contributes to CPU resource limits in the same manner.

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Comment: Facebook updated their official documentation in between the time that this question was asked and answered. Thanks Kevin!

Comment: @RichSutton Nps. Yeah I was thinking something like that :)

Comment: Field Expansion != Batch. A batch sends multiple-but-not-necessarily-related queries to Facebook in a single request. Field expansion is like doing a bunch of joins in SQL. It's only one call.

Answer (score 2):

Based on real-world testing, I've found that field expansion can count for multiple uses under the rate limit. For example, starting from a quiet state, a sequence of 63 field-expanded calls to a single api (graph.facebook.com/IDENTITY/posts) brought us to the 600 call rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/),

> The Field Expansion feature of the Graph API, allows you to effectively "join" multiple graph queries into a single call.

So your queries above would represent four calls in the Batch form, and one call in the Field Expanded form.

As I noted in a comment above: A batch sends multiple-but-not-necessarily-related queries to Facebook in a single request. Field expansion is like doing joins in SQL through a single query.