# Facebook Graph API: I get "Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds." at 38-th API call

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit

My application tries to get `Facebook` page's photos information by sending API requests like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/152623178098449/photos?fields=id,name,from,link,created_time,comments.filter(stream).limit(20).fields(id,message,from,created_time,like_count,comment_count),likes.limit(20).fields(id,profile_type),sharedposts.limit(20).fields(from,id)&limit=25&after=...&access_token=...

It sends 1 call in 1 second, but after 38-th call to API I get:

```
Error: (#613) Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds.
```

I don't use batch requests. Why FB thinks that my application exceeds the limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here: [Do Facebook Graph API calls using field expansion count differently against the rate limits than batch calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626689/do-facebook-graph-api-calls-using-field-expansion-count-differently-against-the/18472015#18472015)

you are using field expansion, and it appears that facebook counts this as additional calls under the rate limit.