# me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(5) gives error code 613 (exceeded 600 calls in 600 seconds)

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am working with rest fb for the first time and am not able to fetch my friends checkins using the above fql query. The query - me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(5) gives me an exception saying

```
{
"error": {    
"message": "(#613) Calls to checkin_fql have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 613 }
}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

May be you are running a batch query, which exceeds the Facebook limit, You can try to run on graph request per second. It tracks one single request per second per auth-token and IP.

Have details on this link 
[Do Facebook Graph API calls using field expansion count differently against the rate limits than batch calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626689/do-facebook-graph-api-calls-using-field-expansion-count-differently-against-the/18472015#18472015)